# Simulator not found after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have just updated the Xcode from App Store from 10.2 to 10.3 and suddenly all the simulators are gone.  Now when I open a project with a storyboard, it throws me an error as below.

> Failed to find or create execution context for description ' System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater  scaleFactor=2x. These intermediate objects were non-nil.

Any one faced this issue before? Also it doesn't let me edit anything in my simulator.

Comment: I also had this issue. I've even downloaded 12.2 simulators manually. But after rebooting the 12.4 simulators appeared :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to restart Xcode, but it did not help.
The only way to fix the problem was to reboot my MacBook - it fixed the problem with simulator

Comment: Restart fixed the issue. Yet to file a bug in apple,

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase deployment target of your project. It worked for me.